# Edit layout of Joomla profile plugin

Tags: joomla

I am using JOOMLA version 3.2, I Want to add or modify  the fields in "Joomla user registration form"  Means i want to add select boxes in registration form, Is it possible to do it?

thanks

Comment: Many extension available for this task in JED http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication/14303 And http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=custom+registration+form

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with a profile plugin. THe core comes with a profile plugin that is a basic example. (You can go to the plugin manager and enabl it and see how it works.)  You can clone that plugin to a new name and add the fields you want and take out those you don't want. This document explains how they work.  http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin.